# interpreting logistic regression results

Tags: logistic, regression-coefficients

I used a continous variable in a logistic regression model.  The sign level is .031.   The Exp(B) is 1.000 and the B is .000.  I'm not sure how to interpret since the B is .000.  How could it be significant but have no influence on the DV?

Comment: `How could it be significant but have no influence on the DV?` Good for you to note that this is weird. Regression hypothesis testing tends to look at reduction in predictive performance according to some criterion upon removing some feature from the model. If there is a large (with that term formalized by the testing machinery) drop in performance, that feature must have some relationship with the outcome. Consequently, could you give more detail about what you’ve done? Your results sound impossible, yet you got them.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is not enough digits, or, alternatively, wrong choice of units. B isn't 0, it's just < 0.001.

Suppose you wanted to look at whether a person's weight was related to their having a heart attack. So, you gather data and do a logistic regression. But you measure weight in metric tons. You could then easily get a significant result with B = 0.000.

So, change your units.

Another possibility is that your N is really, really big. That seems less likely in this case.